# Read text from Wikipedia

Tags: html, vbscript, text-to-speech

Im trying to write a script to get text from a Wikipedia page and read it to me.

This works so far:

```
dim box1
box1 = inputbox("Enter Your Search Term")
URL ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" & box1
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
ie.Navigate(URL) 
wscript.sleep 5000
Data = ie.document.getElementById("content").innerText
set sapi = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak Data
```

But how do i make it skip some stuff from the page? Like skip certain words,or parts of the page while he is reading it to me.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
Data = ie
```

won't work, because `ie` is an object and can't be assigned to a variable without using the `Set` keyword. Not to mention that it won't provide you with the desired information in the first place.

You need to extract the inner text from the `<div>` tag with the ID "content":

```
Data = ie.document.getElementById("content").innerText
```

Comment: Btw,thankyou for helping. Ive been waiting all day for some help,lol.

Comment: @ApatheticEuphoria See updated answer. The inner text might need further cleaning up, but the above should get you started.

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCH,you were a big help,any suggestions on cleaning it up?

Comment: All i want read to me,is the basic information about whatever subject i type in,for example,i type Bill Gates,i want the script to just tell me about Bill gates. I want to skip the jumplist crap,and disambiguiation or whatever,stuff like that. I just want the information.

Comment: Getting "just the information" is a little more complicated than you think, because you need a good understanding of the HTML source structure of Wikipedia pages. This would be way too broad (and way too localized) for SO.